# Get array objects - React

Tags: reactjs

I want to get certain objects from an array.

```
  const array = {[
    0:{
      Emp1: 'John',
      Emp2: 'Simon',
      Emp3: 'Peter'
    },
    1:{
      Emp1: 'Jack',
      Emp2: 'Callum',
      Emp3: 'Paul'
    }
    }];
```

So far I have tried

```
const result = array.reduce((map, obj) => {
    map[obj.Emp1] = obj.Emp1;
    return map;
  }, {});
};
```

which result in

```
{John: John},{jack: jack}
```

But I want to get all the `Emp1` as objects (keys and values) like this

```
{Emp1: John},{Emp1: jack}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` on the array and for each element return a new object with just the `Emp1` property and its value.

**Example**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    Emp1: "John",
    Emp2: "Simon",
    Emp3: "Peter"
  },
  {
    Emp1: "Jack",
    Emp2: "Callum",
    Emp3: "Paul"
  }
];

const result = arr.map(element => {
  return { Emp1: element.Emp1 };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks - but instead of returning as an array - is it possible to return it as objects?

Comment: @fv12345 Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question. I'm not quite sure I understand. How do you want to return multiple objects if not in an array?

Comment: Like this : {Emp1: John},{Emp1: jack}

Comment: `{Emp1: John},{Emp1: jack}` is not valid JavaScript. What do you want to do with them, and why won't an array work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    Emp1: "John",
    Emp2: "Simon",
    Emp3: "Peter"
  },
  {
    Emp1: "Jack",
    Emp2: "Callum",
    Emp3: "Paul"
  }
];

const getElement = (arr,element)=> {
   const result = arr.map(e => {
    let obj ={}
    obj[element] = e[element]
    return obj;
  });
  return result 
}

console.log(getElement(arr,"Emp1"));
console.log(getElement(arr,"Emp2"));
```